# Create shortcut for application on homescreen

Tags: android, icons, homescreen

I am pretty certain this is not a duplicate question.

I have read a lot of articles on creating a shortcut on homescreen to launch your own application, but I am struggling to create an icon for 3rd party app.

I can check if a given package name contains a launch intent by calling  PM.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName).

Once a confirm that the above packageName has a launch intent, I do I use the packageName to create an icon to the default activity when user presses the icon of the package.

Thank you.

Comment: First its not recommended use 3rd party app individual , but in case you want do that just make user install it from play store

Comment: Hi, I am trying to place shortcuts to an already installed app on the homescreen.

Comment: you will have shortcut if you install it as individual app

Answer (score 1):

After further searching and prior hours searching, I could not find the answer, but I finally worked it out myself.  I am pretty certain someone will find this helpful:

```
Intent shortcutIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);

Intent.ShortcutIconResource iconResource = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this, R.drawable.ic_launcher);

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "Shortcut Test");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, iconResource);
intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");

getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
```

The key lies in "getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)"